# USB-C Dock Locks up Laptop on Removal

Tags: kubuntu, dell, usb-c, docking

I have a Dell Precision 5540 running Kubuntu (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS) and a Lasuney USB-C dock. When I've got my computer running and I disconnect the dock, it completely locks up Kubuntu. I have to do a hard shut down to get it to work again. I've upgraded my video drivers, and I've tried with a different "official" USB-C Dell Dock, and the issue occurs there too.

Troubleshooting so far:

- I've reinstalled Kubuntu and the issue persists.
- I tried putting it to sleep before removing the dock.
- Tried a different Dell USB-C Dock.
- Created a different profile and tried from that one.

The only time it's *not* happened is when I booted, logged in, then immediately disconnected the dock. It locked up the Kubuntu panel, but I was able to get to the Konsole.

Comment: Is it still happening for you?  You may want to try to report to r/kde or bugs.kde.org